# Navigations in Gitbook static pages don't work properly

Tags: javascript, gitbook

I recently installed gitbook into my PC and created a simple book for fun. I used `gitbook serve` to serve my book on localhost. And everything worked fine. But when I used `gitbook build` to build a static web page of my book the command exits successfully but I can't use navigation in the static site. Clicking on contents and clicking on side navigations (< and >) does nothing. It sometimes change the address bar of the browser but the page doesn't show up.

I checked my links in the summary page and I can't find anything wrong.

I tested the page with firefox and chrome, but the problem remains.

Why does gitbook fail here?

---

My directory structure is,

```
test
 ├─- README.md
 ├─- SUMMARY.md
 └─- NEXT.md
```

and *SUMMARY.md* is,

```
# Summary

* [Introduction](README.md)
* [Next page](NEXT.md)
```